# jax-ws vs axis2 - help needed

Tags: web-services, jaxb, jax-ws, apache-axis, jaxb2

I need help with the following :

Q.1) Performance comparison between - 
1) lot of war files containing jax-ws based web services deployed on Jetty
2) lot of web services deployed on axis2 running on Jetty

Q.2) Also, if there are many types of clients, like .net, java, c++ based, which are gonna use these web services then which approach should I go with - axis2 as SOAP engine or jax-ws??

Q.3) if I am not interested in WS-* standards then what should I use axis2 or jax-ws?

Q.4) In general why are SOAP engines required?? only for WS-* standard support or do they have more benefits to them???

Answer (score 1):

Java API for XML Web Services (JAX-WS) is just an API.

You need to use a SOAP stack implementation (SOAP engine).

There are 2 major implementations:

- [Axis2](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/)
- [Metro](http://jax-ws.java.net/)

Since Metro provides the Reference Implementations and is shipped with JDK, I assumed you have been calling jax-ws to the RI. But metro is a full SOAP Stack implementation.

Now you that you now the names, and the places, you can start your quest for your favorite implementation. Both have pros and cons.
Keep in mind that both provide you the WS-* standards support, and since SOAP is "programing language independent" doesn't matter the client types.

I personalty prefer Metro, since it is much more easer to use.